# Redis saving strings as buffers on some OSs, not others?

Tags: javascript, macos, node.js, ubuntu, redis

I'm using Redis 2.2.11 with Node on Ubuntu 11.10, and I'm saving a string but it's being returned as a Buffer.

```
    id = 1234;
    console.log('data', data);
    client.hmset("user:" + id, "name", data['name'] );
    client.hmget('user:' + id, "name", function(err, d) {
        console.log('data retrieved', d);
    });
```

This produces the following at the console:

```
data { name: 'RealServer' }
data retrieved [ <Buffer 41 6e 6e 61 52 65 61 6c 53 65 72 76 65 72> ]
```

Why is it going in as a string, and coming out as a Buffer? 
The Buffer makes debugging very difficult!

On my local setup (MacOS 10.6 with Redis 2.2.14) the data retrieved prints as a string, just fine. I'd like to find a solution that continues to work on both systems.

UPDATE: It also works fine without an encoding specified on CentOS 5.7. Is this something specific to Ubuntu? Is there a system-wide fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.3.1/api/buffers.html

> Pure Javascript is Unicode friendly but not nice to binary data. When
>   dealing with TCP streams or the file system, it's necessary to handle
>   octet streams. Node has several strategies for manipulating, creating,
>   and consuming octet streams.
>
> Raw data is stored in instances of the Buffer class. A Buffer is
>   similar to an array of integers but corresponds to a raw memory
>   allocation outside the V8 heap. A Buffer cannot be resized.
>
> The Buffer object is global.
>
> Converting between Buffers and JavaScript string objects requires an
>   explicit encoding method.

Because you've not specified an encoding, it displays as raw data by default. You can use `buffer.toString` to produce a standard JS string.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't specified an encoding it doesn't know what encoding to use while printing it out. Use the toString function with the encoding as a paramater to properly log it.

```
client.hmget('user:' + id, "name", function(err, d) {
    console.log('data retrieved', d.toString('utf8'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Why is this not happening on my MacOS system, though? And is there a global encoding option I can use?

Comment: It also works fine without an encoding specified on CentOS 5.7. Is this something OS-wide? How can I change it in Ubuntu if so?

Comment: I would say that it's better to just specify the encoding, that way it's guaranteed to work on all platforms.