# Express REST API not returning integer array

Tags: node.js, rest, express, redis

I'm using Express for the first time, and I'm running into an issue.  I'm trying to modify [this tutorial](http://www.dreamsyssoft.com/blog/blog.php?/archives/8-Simple-REST-Service-with-Node.js-and-Express.html) and  for my purposes, but I'm using Redis instead of MongoDB.

Here's my code:

**redisSource.js:**

```
var redis = require ("node-redis");

RedisSource = function () {
        this.r_client = redis.createClient();

        this.getParents = function (circuit_id, cb) {
                this.r_client.smembers('circuit.parents_of:' + circuit_id, function(err, reply){
                        console.log("Reply: " + reply);
                        cb(err, reply);
                });
        }
}

exports.RedisSource = RedisSource;
```

**fetch.js:**

```
Fetch = function(app) {
        var RedisSource = require ('./redisSource').RedisSource;
        var redisSource = new RedisSource();

        app.get('/parents/:id', function(req, res) {
                redisSource.getParents(req.params.id, function (error, parents) {
                        console.log ("Response in Fetch main: " + parents);
                        res.send(parents);
                });
        });

        app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
                res.send('Hello, world!');
        });
};

exports.Fetch = Fetch;
```

**app.js:**

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var user = require('./routes/user');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);

var Fetch = require('./fetch').Fetch;
var FetchService = new Fetch(app);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

When I run the application, I get the following:

```
GET http://ironsides.zayo.com:3000/test
> Hello, world!
```

Which is what I expect.  But when I try the other call:

```
GET http://ironsides.zayo.com:3000/parents/12115
> [ [ 49, 53, 50, 55, 51 ], [ 49, 53, 50, 56, 56 ], [ 49, 53, 51, 48, 56 ], [ 49, 53, 51, 48, 57 ], [ 49, 53, 51, 49, 48 ], [ 49, 53, 51, 49, 49 ], [ 49, 53, 51, 50, 56 ], [ 49, 53, 51, 50, 57 ], [ 49, 53, 51, 51, 48 ], [ 49, 53, 51, 52, 49 ], [ 51, 51, 50, 54, 51 ] ]
```

On the console, I get this:

```
GET /parents/12115 200 74ms - 530b
Reply: 15273,15288,15308,15309,15310,15311,15328,15329,15330,15341,33263
Response in Fetch main: 15273,15288,15308,15309,15310,15311,15328,15329,15330,15341,33263
```

I'm expecting an array of the integers that I'm seeing on the console.  Instead, I'm getting an array of arrays of the ascii character codes for those integers.  I'm really confused.  I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

Comment: Have you tried sending the result as JSON?

Comment: @max - Like JSON.stringify?  Yes, same result.

Comment: I mean sending as `res.send({parents: parents});` in `fetch.js`.

Comment: @max - same result, but with with parents: before it and {} around it.

Comment: I think this is the reason:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329252/redis-saving-strings-as-buffers-on-some-oss-not-others

Comment: I believe so; node-redis is returning a buffer if you look at [the docs](https://github.com/Tim-Smart/node-redis)

Comment: max is right. node-redis returns a buffer. When you send it, express will automatically set the `content-type` header to the appropriate type. Run it again, but take a look at the response headers. try `curl -i`.

Comment: BTW, I had similar issues, so I wrapped all of my REST in a lib http://github.com/deitch/booster so I can just do `booster.resource('parent')` and done.

Comment: @deitch -- Booster looks really cool.  Too bad I didn't see it a week ago.  I've bookmarked the page, and will likely use it in future projects.

Comment: @coding_hero that's great! Be sure to open any issues you find.

Comment: @coding_hero what happened with `curl -i`? Did you see the `application/octet-stream` header?

Comment: @deitch - Sorry, I'm not sure.  I discovered the problem and fixed it (see below) about the same time that I got your reply, so I never went down that line of troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Between max's comments, and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329252/redis-saving-strings-as-buffers-on-some-oss-not-others), I figured it out. The 'node-redis' module returns buffers, not strings.  If I rewrite the statement:

```
console.log ("Response in Fetch main: " + parents);
```

as

```
console.log (parents);
```

Then it comes back as an array of buffers.  So I rewrote redisSource.getParents() like this:

```
    this.getParents = function (circuit_id, cb) {
            this.r_client.smembers('circuit.parents_of:' + circuit_id, function(err, reply){
                    console.log("Reply: " + reply);
                    var string_reply = reply.map(function(item) { return item.toString('utf8'); });
                    cb(err, string_reply);
            });
    }
```

As you can see, this will return an array of strings instead of an array of buffers.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
res.send(parents.toString());
```